# How to use the injectinputevent in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I want to make a touch on a button in a layout and also that touch is done by program using injectinputevent method, so that button is clicked even without touching it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `performClick` method on that button.

> Call this view's OnClickListener, if it is defined. Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.

Comment: Yes we can use it, but i'm trying record the touches and playback on rooted phone so that it may work like macro.

Answer (score 0):

You can call if from another method:

```
your_button.performClick();
```